# Finding the rank of certain Mordell curves

Tags: number-theory, algebraic-geometry, elliptic-curves, computational-mathematics, mordell-curves

I am interested in the elliptic curve $y^2 = x^3 + 16r^2$ for various cubefree $r$. (This is related to the elliptic curve $y^2 + ry = x^3$, sums of two rational cubes [A159843](https://oeis.org/A159843), and the recent results of [Alpöge, Bhargava, & Shnidman](https://arxiv.org/abs/2210.10730).)

For example, let $r=54919$. The analytic rank is 2 but I can't prove that its rank is > 0.

Are there any tools I can use to compute these, any places I can look them up, or any good theory to attack them? I know very little about elliptic curves, unfortunately. The curves of interest to me all have large conductors (~$10^9$).

- LMFDB has a [database of elliptic curves](https://www.lmfdb.org/EllipticCurve/Q/) but I can't seem to find the ones I'm looking for there, and can't even search it very well (only by computing some invariants* and searching through the resulting lists).
- Cremona's [Elliptic Curve Data](https://johncremona.github.io/ecdata/) is a wealth of information, but it only has data for conductors less than half a million, so there's nothing there for me.
- [PARI/GP](https://pari.math.u-bordeaux.fr/) has pretty good ability to work with elliptic curves and supplies [ellrank](https://pari.math.u-bordeaux.fr/dochtml/html/Elliptic_curves.html#ellrank) as well as [ellanalyticrank](https://pari.math.u-bordeaux.fr/dochtml/html/Elliptic_curves.html#ellanalyticrank), but these run out of gas eventually.
- mwrank is now only available as [eclib](https://github.com/JohnCremona/eclib), and I haven't been able to build it (it ask me to recompile with -fPIC, and I'm trying, but it's not working).

* There are some easy values: any curve in this family has $j$-invariant 0 and discriminant $-432r^4$.

Comment: I think that, in general, this is beyond the range of what we know how to compute. For example, the solutions to $x^3 + y^3 = 2803$, which correspond to points on $y^2 = x^3 - 432*2803^2$ have denominators of size $O(10^{40})$. If the curve has analytic rank $0$ or $1$, then by progress towards BSD, we know the algebraic rank has to be $0$ or $1$. But for analytic rank $2$ and large $r$, it's probably hopeless. Alpöge-Bhargava-Shnidman's result is statistical: they prove that a positive proportion of these curves have rank $0$ and rank $1$, but they don't say anything about specific curves.

Comment: The LMFDB has every elliptic curve with conductor $\le 500,000$. But with $r = 54919$, the conductor is something like $2^a\cdot3^b\cdot r^2$, so you're several orders of magnitude out of range.

Comment: @Mathmo123 I don't have any conductors less than a million. I suppose that means LMFDB is right out. The Alpöge-Bhargava-Shnidman result, as I understand it (and I don't understand it well!), only concerns ranks 0 and 1.

Comment: I think you'd have to get lucky and be able to find a rational point with small height. But even for 4-digit $r$, the smallest rational point might have height $10^{40}$. ABS's result has rank $>2$ stuff going on under the carpet. One expects that, in the family $y^2 = x^3 + 16r^2$, ordered by $|r|$, $50\%$ of curves have rank 0, $50\%$ have rank 1 and $0\%$ have rank greater than $1$. So for a statistical result, you're not going to be able to say much about curves with rank $>2$. The fact that ABS can't get down to 50-50 is because they can't rule out the existence of many high rank twists.

Comment: Do all your curves have analytic rank $\ge2$?

Comment: @Mathmo123 Yes, all the curves of interest have analytic rank $\ge2$. (Otherwise their rank is equal to analytic rank and I'm done.)

Comment: I will be able to help with all the curves of interest. Please send me an email. Third author here: https://arxiv.org/pdf/2106.06861.pdf.

Comment: What is your highest suspected rank now? How high are you trying to get?

Comment: @Mathmo123 > ...it's probably hopeless... Not really that hopeless anymore in 2023. For [0,0,0,0,-432*2803^2], the rank is 1, P1 = [572903507653175612229990278332/334693450859084090717257521, 
246542993060076749698481061829912260621097900/6123092517789736976780724484130799433431]. Even it was due to HeegnerPoint for rank 1 in Magma, we have accumulated some experience to find generators up to a certain height. The height here is ~62. What rank/height is expected? Rank 8 on similar curves was recently found (bottom of the page): https://web.math.pmf.unizg.hr/~duje/tors/z3old891011121314.html.

Comment: For a cubefree r = 26051335428690, the rank = 8.

Comment: After checking ~5500 curves of rank 3, I wouldn't expect any trouble in Magma for r <= 10^6. Rank 2 might be tougher, please provide the values of r for the curves of interest.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

[Magma](http://magma.maths.usyd.edu.au/magma/) is fairly good at computing Mordell–Weil groups of elliptic curves and sometimes succeeds where other libraries fail. For example, it successfully computes the Mordell–Weil group of the curve you mentioned in about 13 seconds on my laptop (running Magma 2.27-1):

```
E := EllipticCurve([0, 16*54919^2]);
A, mw, rank_proven, saturation_proven := MordellWeilGroup(E);
[mw(A.1), mw(A.2), mw(A.3)];
```

The booleans `rank_proven` and `saturation_proven` are both true, which means the full Mordell–Weil group has been provably computed. The first generator is the 3-torsion point $(0 : 219676 : 1)$, generating the torsion subgroup. The other two generators, generating the $\mathbb{Z}^2$ part, are
$$(-74715322416/21390625 : -7431687117209948/98931640625 : 1)$$
and
$$(\tfrac{-223505436219321136916938970992760345077374165859681250008575245328}{145217979187124628448668425810330104026209934618656495346234121} : \tfrac{-369619409961856952324804801809068062165946757491071404180443310935789117344859520908282493098069772}{1749969918763739600846483096788677644836465031382404342922206701087180078045471050628765268581} : 1).$$
Of course, as you said, such methods can only go so far before the computation becomes infeasible, but perhaps this will work for more of the particular curves of interest to you.

Comment: I will be able to help with all the curves of interest. Please send me an email. Third author here: arxiv.org/pdf/2106.06861.pdf.

Comment: [0, 16*r^2] is a Z3 curve. 3-descent (full or by 3-isogeny) seems to be done fast. 2-descent and 4-descent seem to work too. 6-descent and 12-descent are the next available options. The height(P2) here is ~150. With the 12-descent we can reach height ~1200 reasonably fast. Look at our last 55 Z12 curves of rank 3: https://web.math.pmf.unizg.hr/~duje/tors/z12old3.html.

Comment: @MaksymVoznyy Very cool! Are the algorithms you used for this implemented in Magma or another computer algebra system with code available somewhere to try out?

Comment: Our work is all in Magma, it is the strongest product right now. We sometimes use SageMath to run Bober's analytic rank estimates because it supports multithreading. PARI/GP could be comparable to Magma at some stages of the process, but you are almost always finishing with Magma these days. I am waiting for the curves of interest from Charles, and then can provide Magma code to solve some extreme cases that even Magma would not finish by any standard procedures.